# Fish-shell throws error on startup. Wrong number of arguments

Tags: shell, terminal, fish

I have been using fish-shell on a mac for a few months with no issues.  All of a sudden, when I open the terminal I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish (line 1): 
uname
^
in command substitution
    called on line 1 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish

from sourcing file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish
    called on line 2 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish

in command substitution
    called on line 2 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish

in command substitution
    called on line 3 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish

in function 'fish_title'
    called on standard input

in command substitution
    called on standard input

/usr/local/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish (line 1): switch: Expected exactly one argument, got 0

switch (uname)
       ^
from sourcing file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish
    called on line 2 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish

in command substitution
    called on line 2 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish

in command substitution
    called on line 3 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish

in function 'fish_title'
    called on standard input

in command substitution
    called on standard input

/usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish (line 1): 
__fish_pwd
^
in command substitution
    called on line 3 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish

in function 'fish_title'
    called on standard input

in command substitution
    called on standard input
```

I see there is an issue with the number of arguments. However, it appears that there is 1 argument even though it says there is 0. Here are the contents of the __fish_pwd.fish file:

```
switch (uname)
    case 'CYGWIN_*'
        function __fish_pwd --description "Show current path"
            pwd | sed -e 's-^/cygdrive/\(.\)/\?-\u\1:/-'
        end
    case '*'
        function __fish_pwd --description "Show current path"
            pwd
        end
end
```

Here are the contents of config.fish when it wasn't working. Removing the last line `export PATH=$M3:$PATH` solved the problem.

```
# put ~/.local/bin/ in my path
set PATH ~/.local/bin $PATH

# spark
set SPARK_HOME /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4
set PATH $SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
set -x PYSPARK_PYTHON python3.7

# sbt: build tool for scala and java
export M3_HOME=/usr/local/etc/sbtopts
export M3=$M3_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M3:$PATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, it appears that there is 1 argument even though it says there is 0.

Well, not really.

The 1 argument it wants is *after expansion*. In this case it runs `uname`, and uses its output as the argument to `switch`.

You appear to have changed something about your system so that `uname` doesn't print anything anymore - perhaps you added a function called `uname`, or you changed $PATH so that `uname` isn't included anymore.

Comment: Ok I have change my $PATH recently.  I haven't made a function named `uname` though.

Comment: So you'll have to check if `uname` prints anything, and if it doesn't check `type uname`. It should tell you what kind of thing fish thinks it is. Then you'll have to fix that.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  So I fixed the problem by commenting out some things I had recently added to config.fish, specifically `export PATH=$M3:$PATH` which I thought I needed to get [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Mac.html) to work.  Without commenting out that line, I couldn't use any command (that I tried) in my terminal besides `cd` due to the error.  So I get the same error when I tried to run `uname`.

Comment: I added the contents of my config to the question